# size of OSX Yosemite, don't understand who only 40 GB let on HD

Tags: macos, hard-drive

I installed Yosemite 10.4 on my 500 GB MBP hard drive.
I only have 40 Gb left.
Though i have :
Pictures 88 GB
Music 60 GB
Movies 5 GB
Documents 4 GB
Dropbox 6 GB
Desktop 0 GB
Downloads 1 GB
for a total of 164 GB out of 500 GB.
I have 40 GB left so this sum up 204 GB.
What is taking the rest of my space 500-204=296 GB?
Can't imagine that Yosemite+Recovery HD takes 296 GB inlcuding Library and System folders.

Please is there any explanation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

DiskInventoryX will allow you to view a diagram of every file of your Mac and parts will be larger relative to file size. You can find it here: http://www.derlien.com/ This should allow you to find what's taking up so much space on your Mac.

Comment: good tool though didnot tell me what were "others" files. thanks

Comment: @Thomas It should show every single file on your drive. The other files are any files that aren't .app, an audio file, a photo file, or a video file. So things like .docx or .txt would be an other. DiskInventoryX helps you find large files, if you want an exact description of what apple classifies as "other" check out this help doc: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202867